# Jenkins Remote Trigger Not Working

Tags: curl, jenkins

I am getting the following error when i try triggering a build using the following command:

curl http://jenkins_server:port/jenkins/job/job_name/build?token=token_name

Output:

> Authentication required
>
> <--
>   You are authenticated as: anonymous
>   Groups that you are in:
>
> Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
>   ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
>   ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
>   ->

I have admin rights and have also enabled 'Authentication Token'. I also have Build, Discover and Read rights on Job. I am using Jenkins 1.614.

I did check several posts online but could not find anything that works for me.
 Tried few options such as
1) curl -X POST http://jenkins_server:port/jenkins/job/job_name/build?token=token_name
2) curl -u user:API  (Prints a long HTML page)

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I install Build Token Root Plugin to solve this issue before

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin

Then as the same, setup Authentication Token

Finally, either use curl to trigger remote build (Be careful the escape character "\")

`curl http://JENKINS_URL/buildByToken/build?job=JOB_NAME\&token=TOKEN_NAME`

or paste the URL to your browser (No needs escape character "\")

`http://JENKINS_URL/buildByToken/build?job=JOB_NAME&token=TOKEN_NAME`

If you see Succeed, it means that trigger remote Jenkins successfully.

Note that, you don't have to setup build, discover, and read rights on Job

For more information, you could reference to 
https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204338790-Why-are-builds-not-being-triggered-with-Build-Token-Root-Plugin-

Comment: I was really frustrated trying out different things. I'm sure i saw this Token Root plugin suggestion on some other link as well and i did notice that the plugin was already installed on my system but looks like i overlooked the syntax that time. :( While reading your answer, somehow, i did notice the correct syntax. :P Thanks a lot man! :) Quite relieved! :)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the need for an escape char. that was missing for me.

Comment: I get same problem when trying to integrate gitlab and jenkins. I am using the gitlab inbuild feature to test push trigger. Which throws me the above error. What can be done to solve it in my case

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung I had use GitLab to trigger Jenkins with webhook, everything go well. Could you describes in detail the error throws?

Answer (score 17):

I think there's no need to set up any kind of plugin to make it works, simply do this BATCH CMD:

```
curl -X POST http://USER_ID_JENKINS_RECEIVER:TOKEN_OF_USER_ID_JENKINS_RECEIVER@URL_JENKINS_RECEIVER:PORT/job/NAME_OF_JOB/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_JOB_JENKINS_RECEIVER
```

- To see you **USER_ID_TOKEN**, go to your username at the top-right of jenkins > go to Configure > Click on API Token and it will be displayed.
- You must configure a token on the **JOB_OF_JENKINS_RECEIVER**

I have to say that it works perfectly on Jenkins without any kind of permissions to anonymous users.

Comment: I get same problem when trying to integrate gitlab and jenkins. I am using the gitlab inbuild feature to test push trigger. Which throws me the above error. What can be done to solve it in my case

Comment: Worked for me when I provided a CSRF crumb header, detailed here; https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem after setting up a test Jenkins server. The solution was to authenticate using my Jenkins admin password:

```
curl -u admin:<mypassword> http://localhost:8080/job/Test/build?token=<mytoken>
```

Use the same username and password you use to login to Jenkins. There was no need to install additional plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try [Jenkins Python API](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-jenkins). It provides an `build_job` action that is super easy to trigger a job.

```
build_job(name, parameters=None, token=None)
   Trigger build job.

   Parameters:  
   name – name of job
   parameters – parameters for job, or None, dict
   token – Jenkins API token
```

Comment: Since JenTing's suggestion worked for me, for now, i'll go for that but thanks for your suggestion! This API might come handy sometime. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had the URL and token correct, but had forgotten one of the required permissions for the API user that triggers the URL/build.

The permissions have to minimally include the list here:

- Overall - Read
- Job - Build
- Job - Read
- Job - Workspace

Answer (score 0):

Install Parameterized Build plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

If you are using an authorization token to trigger the builds (Job -> Configure -> 'Build Triggers' -> 'Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)'), you can access:

`curl -X POST http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value`

Comment: The plugin is already installed and as i already mentioned in my post, i tried the suggested syntax but it's not working. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

On 1.625.3, giving Anonymous read access to almost everything worked for me.

**UPDATE**: I guess I should clarify since this got downvoted. I was able to reproduce that error message, and when I turned on read access for the Anonymous user on all of the access types, it resolved the problem. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the same issue and resolved it.

Consider, you have 2 Jenkins A and B. If you want to execute a build job present in Jenkins B, then you have to give the API token of Jenkins B. If you provide the API token of Jenkins A, it will show the authentication issue only.

This is the mistake I have did and it got resolved once I have changed the API token properly according to the required Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

This works  for me:

tokenuser =  You need login with the user and check token config jenkins -> admin users

user = username

```
curl -XPOST --silent --show-error --user user:tokenuser "http://ipserver/jenkins/buildByToken/build?job=JOBNAME&token=7RJWiIwD5cW3S6QjwF7a"
```

Example:

```
curl -XPOST --silent --show-error --user desarrollador:b9611288e4159ea9fb7857faeadd06fe "http://ipserver/jenkins/buildByToken/build?job=DeployGF&token=7RJWiIwD5cW3S6QjwF7a"
```