# Jenkins security and trigger remote build

Tags: jenkins

I want to run build after push to repository.
I configured jenkins to use `Matrix-based security`, to protect my jenkins server. But when I do this I can't trigger build.
In build I checked `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` and I added Authentication Token `XXXXXXXXXXX`, but when I run:

```
curl -XPOST http://my-jenkins/job/test/build?token=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I receive error and message `Authentication required`.

Is it possible configure Jenkins to run remote builds and configure Matrix-based security to don't allow anonymous users to do any action?

Comment: Instead of using Jenkin's security, you can allow Jenkins to listen only 127.0.0.1 and create a virtual host in your webserver to reverse proxy requests to jenkins. This allows you to use a simple basic auth (and, as a plus, you can put your jenkins under ssl)

Comment: I can't resign from Matrix-based security, because some users shouldn't run builds. There is other option?

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409149/jenkins-remote-trigger-not-working)